# В чём состоит ошибка при создании GUI на Groovy

Tags: gui, groovy

Код, взятый из книги Башар Абдул-Джавада, согласно автору должен создать GUI с текстовым полем, кнопкой и меню с одним пунктом.

И после введения текста и нажатия на кнопку происходит вывод текста в виджете.

Когда я пробую выполнить в groovyConsole.exe (Ctrl+R) - действует...

Когда я выполняю ###.groovy, нет - почему?

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder
import javax.swing.JOptionPane 

swing = new SwingBuilder()
showText = swing.action(name: 'Show Text', closure: {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, message.text)})
frame = swing.frame(title: 'Action Demo'){
  menuBar{
    menu('Tools'){
      menuItem('Show text', action: showText)
   }
}
panel(){
  message = textField(columns: 10)
  widget(button)
   }
}
button = swing.button(text: 'Show text', action: showText)
frame.pack()
frame.show()
```

Comment: *Когда я выполняю ###.groovy, нет*  - поясните как вы это делаете?

Comment: *Теперь следующий вопроc*  - оформите его отдельным вопросом. при необходимости сохранить контекст - добавьте ссылку на этот.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поместить вот эту строчку

```
button = swing.button(text: 'Show text', action: showText)
```

До

```
frame = swing.frame(title: 'Action Demo'){
```

Получиться вот так

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder

import javax.swing.*

swing = new SwingBuilder()
showText = swing.action(name: 'Show Text', closure: {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, message.text)
})
button = swing.button(text: 'Show text', action: showText)
frame = swing.frame(title: 'Action Demo') {
    menuBar {
        menu('Tools') {
            menuItem('Show text', action: showText)
        }
    }
    panel() {
        message = textField(columns: 10)
        widget(button)
    }
}
frame.pack()
frame.show()
```

Скорей всего это исправит вашу проблему.